# ESXi 5.0 not showing RAID Health status (DELL PERC H200)

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, health, dell-perc

Hi we have installed VmWare ESXi 5.0 on brand new Dell T410 II.
Hypervisor sees storage but we are somehow missing the Health status in VI client.

We have PERC H200 in RAID 1.

We shortly tried the ESXi 4.1 and that showed health status ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's an ESXi 5 release that contains Dell-specific support at the moment. You may get most of the hardware status except for the RAID controller.

[Here's one workaround from someone with the same issue.](http://blog.rebelit.net/?p=283) It involves obtaining the LSI ESXi drivers and loading them onto the system.

Also see Dell's OpenManage notes at:
http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/OpenManage+Support+for+VMware+ESX+5.0#fbid=xP07u_QFJVJ

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VIB File of MegaRAID SAS 9240-4i since this also uses LSISAS2008. Download:
http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/00.03.V0.03_SMIS_VMware_Installer.zip

and install the .vib file on the ESX-Server . More or less the same instructions as here: http://blog.rebelit.net/?p=283 .. just you have to install the .vib file in the .zip file, not the .zip itself. see vmware documentation to install .vib directly (use --force)

I can now see my PERC H200 in ESXi 5

Answer (score 1):

The VmWare was downloaded from DELL pages here: http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&releaseid=R312519&SystemID=PWE_T410&servicetag=HWQM45J&os=EX50&osl=en&deviceid=23823&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=47&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=473123

that is the version which doesnt show the health status.

I have found this blog: http://blog.rebelit.net/?p=283
and will try to install LSI drivers.

I will let you know as soon as i get to it.

Thanks anyway.
p.

Comment: This operation was not successfull so i will be diging around..